# Simple HTML DOM Parser in input field

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get all results from the DOM parser, but I'm getting only the last  tag in the input field. If I echo $link isn't a problem. Is there a solution to get all text like I'm getting from echo?

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

// Create DOM from URL or file
$link = "https://www.sofascore.com/fr/sevilla-real-betis/qgbsIgb";

foreach ($html->find('div.Header__Main-sc-1dyxed1-0.hkVBhG ul li') as $element){
    $links = $element->find('a');
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        echo $link->plaintext.'<br/>';
    }
}
?>

<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $link->plaintext?>"><br>
```

Here is the github: https://github.com/inbazhlekov/domm

Id want the value in the input field to be: "Football Espagne LaLiga", not only "LaLiga".

Comment: $link is your last text in loop. Assing $link->plaintext to a variable like $inputValue. So you code should be like this `$inputValue .= $link->plaintext;`. And don't forget change value of input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop will overwrite `$element` and `$link` on each iteration of their respective loops. If you want to access all values after the loop, you need to store the values in a variable.

You could store them in an array:

```
$link = "https://www.sofascore.com/fr/sevilla-real-betis/qgbsIgb";

// Initiate the array we'll use to store the values
$name = [];

foreach ($html->find('div.Header__Main-sc-1dyxed1-0.hkVBhG ul li') as $element){
    $links = $element->find('a');

    foreach ($links as $link) {
        // Push the values into our array instead of echoing them
        $name[] = $link->plaintext;
    }
}
?>
```

When you want to output it, [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the array with a space as delimiter:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?= implode(' ', $name)  ?>"><br>
```